CORS Error in Playwright: Unable to Access Login API from Origin Domain
Error message: "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://xxxxx.jp/v1/login' from origin 'https://xxxxx.jp' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."
Of course, this error does not occur when running in a normal browser such as Chrome instead of playwright.
A CORS error occurs only when running in playwright, and since I cannot resolve this issue, I am unable to log in, which is causing me a lot of trouble.

Checked on other sites with different login mechanisms and confirmed that the same test code does not result in an error
If OPTIONS is not set in the header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods', preflight will not work and a 500 error screen will appear, so this is set additionally
Explicitly specifying the URL with the CORS error in 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' does not resolve the issue
https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/17631 I tried adding settings based on this but the problem persisted.


Please share the page and a [mcve] of your code. Puppeteer shouldn't be doing anything significantly different from a normal browser, so it shouldn't cause a CORS error, unless the server is somehow detecting and blocking you.
